# From Hausdorff maximal principle to well-ordering principle

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

How to prove the well-ordering principle if we have known the Hausdorff maximal principle?

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a non-empty set, and let $P$ be the collection of all partial well-orders, i.e. all the well orders of subsets of $A$. We order by me extension, i.e. $R<S$ iff $R$ is a proper initial segment of $S$.

By Hausdorff Maximality Principle we have a maximal chain, its union is a well-ordering of $A$. Denote this order by $R$. It should be fairly clear how to show that the domain of $R$ is $A$ (Hint: it follows from the maximality of the chain).

Suppose $\varnothing\neq B\subseteq A$, then $B$ is a subset of the domain of $R$, so there exists some $S$ which is a well-order of a subset of $A$ whose domain contains at least one point from $B$. Since $S$ is a well-order and $B\cap\operatorname{dom}(S)$ is non-empty there exists a minimal element there. Now you have to show that this minimal element is actually $R$-minimal (Hint: it follows from the definition of $<$ on the collection of well-orders).

Comment: Well, wakey wakey eggs and... err...  ummm... something kosher, I guess.

Comment: I'm a fan of bacon... :-)

Comment: I know _you_ are, but your country doesn't appear to be. ;-)

Comment: You should have seen it 15 years ago. It was much much much worse.

Comment: How can I prove that there exists a minimal element in A under this order?

Comment: @LiXinghe: I'm sorry for the late reply. I edited to give a guideline on how to approach this problem. I left you some of the work, but included hints.